# How does ASP.Net Web API use thread to handle requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, rest, asp.net-web-api

It's my first time to use `Web API` to build a service. It's a chat service that takes a request from a mobile user and pass that request to a `Contact Center Infrastructure system`. The goal of the service is to enable mobile users to chat with a live support person.

The connection from the `Web API` service to the `Contact Center Infrastructure` may take a second or 2. It was proposed that we spawn a thread for each request. I was wondering if this is necessary. In the back of my head I have the impression that `Web API` natively spawn threads to handle each request. I've done some research online and the results I got back are not explicit on this matter.

Please advice.

Comment: In a web environment spawning a thread for each operation won't scale very well.  You'll starve the threadpool of threads.  If you need to manage a lot of requests, look into the async/await patterns (assuming your requests are likely to be IO bound).

Comment: @GrantH. Creating new threads explicitly *won't* starve the thread pool.  *Not* creating new threads would starve the thread pool.  it would however potentially over-saturate the CPU, and consume a lot of memory and other system resources.

Comment: @Servy, you are correct, my bad.  What I was getting at is that thread creation is expensive, so deliberately starting a thread with each request will not scale well.  Allowing the thread pool to reuse existing threads will result in better performance (typically).